# Assigning events to calender dates in R

Tags: r, datetime, random, sampling, experimental-design

This is for creating sampling design for my experiment. I want to survey 8 different individuals on every Monday of the year 2018. Order in which I survey them needs to be random for each Monday. For eg. A,B,C,D... for one Monday and then for next C,B,A,D....

To try this with R, I have a list of names: `namelist<- ("A", "B", "C",...)` containing 8 different names. I want to assign these in random order to every Monday in a year. For this, I have created a list of dates for the entire year 2018. `X<- ("01-01-2018", "02-01-2018",...)` and list of corresponding weekdays `Y<- ("Monday", "Tuesday",...)`.

I need the entire namelist assigned in random order for all the Mondays in the year. What is the best way to go about it? Can I use for-loop for this? or is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `sample()` function in a `for` loop to randomly sample from your name list into a dataframe:

Get all the Mondays in the year and create namelist:

```
dates = as.Date("2018-01-01") +7*(0:52)
namelist = c("A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H")
```

You've not specified how you want the output to look, but here is are two choices:

**Multi Column approach:**

```
samples=matrix(0,length(dates),length(namelist))
for(i in 1:length(dates)){samples[i,]=sample(namelist)}
df=data.frame(dates,samples)

> head(df)
       dates X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6 X7 X8
1 2018-01-01  E  G  B  D  H  C  A  F
2 2018-01-08  F  D  B  C  G  H  A  E
3 2018-01-15  A  E  H  D  B  C  G  F
4 2018-01-22  E  C  F  H  A  D  G  B
5 2018-01-29  C  E  F  B  G  H  A  D
6 2018-02-05  C  G  A  H  D  F  B  E
```

**Single Column approach:**

```
df2 = data.frame(dates, samples_char="")
for(i in 1:nrow(df2)){df2[i,'samples_char']=paste0(sample(namelist),collapse=", ")}

> head(df2)
       dates           samples_char
1 2018-01-01 E, A, G, D, C, B, F, H
2 2018-01-08 B, E, F, A, C, H, G, D
3 2018-01-15 H, D, E, C, F, A, G, B
4 2018-01-22 G, F, A, D, E, H, C, B
5 2018-01-29 A, E, D, H, G, C, B, F
6 2018-02-05 C, H, G, F, E, B, D, A
```

Comment: Thank you. The multicolumn approach works. However, for single column approach, I am getting following error.  In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, iseq, value = "F, D, E, H, G, C, B, A") :  invalid factor level, NA generated.

Comment: Thank you. The multicolumn approach works. However, for single column approach, I am getting following error.    <In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, iseq, value = "F, D, E, H, G, C, B, A") :  invalid factor level, NA generated.>

Comment: Is it possible to do this without extracting Mondays because I want to do similar loops for every weekday for different namelists?

Answer (score 0):

```
#I have figured this out. Thank you#
  ##Create calender and list of names for Group01, empty variable for random order and make a dataframe##
Startdate<- as.Date("2017-12-4")
Date<-Startdate + 0:365
Day<-weekdays(FullCalendar)
MONTHS<-months(FullCalendar)
Focal_Order<-""
Group<- ""
Focal_Calender<-data.frame(Date, Day, Group, Focal_Order , stringsAsFactors 
= FALSE)
head(Focal_Calender)
Group01<- c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H")
## Use For  loop to assign random order to every Monday ##
for(i in 1:nrow(Focal_Calender) ){
  if(Focal_Calender[i,2]=='Monday'){
  Focal_Calender[i,'Focal_Order']=paste0(sample(Group01),collapse=", ")
  Focal_Calender[i,'Group']=paste0("Group 01")}
  else {}
}
head(Focal_Calender)
Focal_Calender
write.csv(Focal_Calender, file = "Focal_Calender.csv",row.names=FALSE, 
na="")
```